# Define thread in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I start a thread using `_beginthreadex()`, making it execute `void myFunction(wchar_t *param);`?   I try to use this:

```
_beginthread(NULL, 0, myFunction, L"someParam", 0, &ThreadID);
```

but there is compilation error:

> error C2664: '*beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void (*_cdecl *)(wchar_t *)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'.

How I can resolve this error?   I seem able to do `_beginthread((void(*)(void*))myFunction, 0 , (void *)L"someParam");`. But for `_beginthreadex()` these casts don't seem to work. What do 
I need to do?
This code doesn't output anything. What's wrong?

```
unsigned int __stdcall myFunction( void *someParam )
{
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, myFunction, L"param", 0, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Andres Jaan Tack It's WINAPI project

Comment: If the question relates to a particular library/api that should be listed in the tags to better help identifying the scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function prototype requirements for each Microsoft CRT thread launch functions are:

- **[_beginthread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**: `void __cdecl procname(void * arg);`
- **[_beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**: `unsigned int __stdcall procname(void *arg);`

You should also be aware of the differences between the two.

- **_beginthread**: allocates a new thread and invokes the thread procedure passed as the argument. Using this API the thread-creation parameters are somewhat limited. The return value of this function is a uintptr_t, but is actually a Windows thread handle of type HANDLE. It must be cast to a HANDLE variable to be used in such functions as `WaitForSingleObject`, etc. When the thread procedure finishes through normal function-exit the thread handle is automatically closed for you by the runtime. **This is important**. Although this function returns a thread handle just like _beginthreadex, it is conceivable for the thread to start *and finish* before you can do anything with the handle (such as a wait, suspend, etc.). Once the thread procedure finishes the RT will close the handle, and therefore your local variable holding the initial returned handle is now invalid.
- **_beginthreadex**: allocates a new thread and invokes the thread procedure passed as the argument. This version allows significantly more control over how the thread is created, including the stack size, initial suspended state, etc. The return value of this function is a uintptr_t, but is actually a Windows thread handle of type HANDLE. It must be cast to a HANDLE variable to be used in such functions as `WaitForSingleObject`, etc. When the thread procedure finishes through normal function-exit the thread handle is **NOT** automatically closed for you by the runtime. **You are responsible for closing the thread handle returned by this function, and should do so as soon as it is no longer needed**.

Which to use: Use `_beginthread` if you have no need for the thread handle to be used in Wait functions and such, and have no special thread-creation needs (like creating a thread with an initially-suspended state). Use `_beginthreadex` when you need a wait'able thread handle, finer control over the creation parameters, etc.

EDIT: Sample for the OP

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

unsigned int __stdcall MyThread(void *p)
{
    _tprintf(_T("%s\n"), p);
    _tprintf(_T("Thread finishing!\n"));
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MyThread, _T("Hello, World!"), 0, NULL);
    if (hThread != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hThread);
        _tprintf(_T("Thread finished!\n"));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works, but in Richter's book "Windows via c++" I've read that I can use somethink like that HANDLE hThread = _beginthreadex(...); In my case that doesn't work, but single _beginthreadex() with signature that you describe correct. What can be wrong?

Comment: cast the return result to a handle: `HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(...)`, but as I said above, if you don't *need* the handle for things like wait-functions, just use `_beginthread` instead. If you do need the extra flexibility of `_beginthreadex`, be sure to close the returned handle using [CloseHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx) when you no longer need it.

Comment: O sorry, but It just compile without errors. Next code unsigned int __stdcall myFunction( void *someParam )
{
    printf("Hello world!");
 return 0;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, myFunction, L"param", 0, NULL);
 return 0;
}

Comment: this code doesn't output anything. I'll add it to my question in a moment

Comment: @Vsevywniy updated to include a sample of calling _beginthreadex, and how to use (and close) the returned thread handle.

Answer (score 5):

`_beginthreadex` requires a function that uses the `__stdcall` [calling convention](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx), not the `__cdecl` calling convention, which is the default.  To fix it, declare your thread procedure with the `__stdcall` calling convention:

```
unsigned int __stdcall myFunction(void *arg)
{
    ...
}
```

Do NOT cast the function pointer you're passing into `_beginthread` or `_beginthreadex`: [a function pointer cast is a bug waiting to happen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx).

Comment: Should I return something from function signature that you describe?

Comment: Yes, you should return something to be the thread exit status (0 if you have nothing else).  What is the error you're having?

Comment: I try to return 0.I've got next three errors:Error 1 error C2664: '_beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void *(__stdcall *)(void *)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'
 2 IntelliSense: a value of type "uintptr_t" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "HANDLE" 
 3 IntelliSense: argument of type "void *(__stdcall *)(void *folder)" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)"

Comment: Sorry, I had the return type wrong -- it should be `unsigned int`, not `void *`.  You also need to cast the return value of `_beginthreadex` from `uintptr_t` to `HANDLE`.

Answer (score 0):

As in the other answer above, don't forget to wait for your thread to finish before _tmain exits, or you likely will see no output.